# Subversion Edge Windows - Incremental Backups

Tags: powershell, subversion-edge, incremental

I am running a Subversion edge on windows to host my repository. hot dump and full dumps are getting out of hands. I am looking into take incremental backups on daily basis, perhaps using a PowerShell?

Any help would be appreciated.

svnadmin --incremental

Comment: FYI: CollabNet stopped supporting their SVN server product "SVN Edge". You can consider VisualSVN Server as a replacement for SVN Edge. And VisualSVN Server has scheduled incremental backup jobs: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/